# Run a perl script with Python on multiple files at once in a folder

Tags: python, perl

This is my perl script at the moment:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use open qw/:std :utf8/;
use strict;
use warnings;

if (defined $ARGV[0]){
my $filename = $ARGV[0];
my %count;

open (my $fh, $filename) or die "Can't open '$filename' $!";
while (<$fh>)
{
        $count{ lc $1 }++ while /(\w+)/g;
}
close $fh;

my $array = 0;

foreach my $word ( sort { $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} } keys %count)
{
    print "$count{$word} $word\n" if $array++ < 10;
}

}else{
print "Please enter the name of the file: ";
my $filename = ($_ = <STDIN>);

my %count;

open (my $fh, $filename) or die "Can't open '$filename' $!";
while (<$fh>)
{
        $count{ lc $1 }++ while /(\w+)/g;
}
close $fh;

my $array = 0;

foreach my $word ( sort { $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} } keys %count)
{
    print "$count{$word} $word\n" if $array++ < 10;
}
}
```

And this is my Python script at the moment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

perlscript = "perl " + " perlscript.pl " + " /home/user/Desktop/data/*.txt " + " >> " + "/home/user/Desktop/results/output.txt"
os.system(perlscript)
```

**Problem**: When there are multiple txt-files in the data folder the script only runs on one file and ignores all the other txt-files. Is there a way to run the perlscript on all the txt-files at once?

**Another problem:** I'm also trying to delete the txt-files with the os.remove after they have been executed but they get deleted before the perlscript has a chance to execute.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: in Pythin use `glob.glob()` or `os.listdir()` to get all files in directory and run perl script in `for` loop with every file separatelly. Or you have to create loop in perl script which will get next filename(s) from `ARGV[1]`, `ARGV[2]`, etc. As I remeber `perl` can use `shift` to get next element from `ARGV`.

Comment: When on Unix or Linux try to change `if (defined $ARGV[0]){
my $filename = $ARGV[0];` to `foreach my $filename (@ARGV) {`.

Comment: @furas Thank you! It worked with glob!

Answer (score 3):

That Perl script processes one file. Also, that string passed to shell via `os.system` doesn't get expanded into a valid command with a file list as intended with the `*` shell glob.

Instead, build the file list in Python, using `os.listdir` or `glob.glob` or `os.walk`. Then iterate over the list and call that Perl script on each file, if it must process only one file at a time. Or, modify the Perl script to process multiple files and run it once with the whole list.

To keep the current Perl script and run it on each file

```
import os

data_path   = "/home/user/Desktop/data/"
output_path = "/home/user/Desktop/result/"

for file in os.listdir(data_path):
    if not file.endswith(".txt"):
        continue

    print("Processing " + file)                      # better use subprocess
    run_perlscript = "perl " + " perlscript.pl " + \
        data_path + file  + " >> " + output_path + "output.txt"
    os.system(run_perlscript)
```

The Perl script need be rewritten to lose that unneeded code duplication.

However, it is better to use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module to run and manage external commands. This is advised even in the [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20system#os.system) documentation itself.
For instance

```
import subprocess

with open(output_path + "output.txt", "a") as fout:
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if not file.endswith(".txt"):
            continue 
        subprocess.run(["perl", "script.pl", data_path + file], stdout=fout)
```

where the file is opened in the append mode (`"a"`) following the question's `>>` redirection.

The recommended [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) is available since python 3.5; otherwise use [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Another, and arguably "right," option is to adjust the Perl script so that it can process multiple files. Then you only need run it once, with the whole file list.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';    
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

foreach my $filename (@ARGV) {
    say "Processing $filename";

    my %count;

    open my $fh, '<', $filename  or do {
       warn "Can't open '$filename': $!";
       next;
    };
    while (<$fh>) {   
        $count{ lc $1 }++ while /(\w+)/g;
    }   
    close $fh;

    my $prn_cnt = 0;
    foreach my $word ( sort { $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} } keys %count) {   
        print "$count{$word} $word\n" if $prn_cnt++ < 10; 
    }   
}
```

This prints a warning on a file that it can't open and skips to the next one. If you'd rather have the script exit on any unexpected file replace `or do { ... };` with the original `die`.

Then, and using [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html?highlight=glob%20glob#glob.glob) as an example now

```
import subprocess

data_path   = "/home/user/Desktop/data/"
output_path = "/home/user/Desktop/result/"

files = glob.glob(data_path + "*.txt")

with open(output_path + "output.txt", "a") as fout:
    subprocess.run(["perl", "script.pl", files], stdout=fout)
```

Since this passes the whole list as command arguments it assumes that there aren't (high) thousands of files, to exceed some length limits on pipes or command-line.